# Different methods to create graphic when using graphics.py

Tags: python-3.x, zelle-graphics

I'm using `graphics.py` to create some objects, but have this question - What are the differences between:

```
L1 = win.create_line(x1, y1 , x2, y2)
```

And:

```
L1 = Line(Point(x1,y1), Point(x2,y2))
L1.draw(win)
```

Do they have different function and what is the name of the two method?

Answer (score 0):

(Zelle) graphics.py is higher level, simpler graphics package implemented atop of another lower level, more sophisticated graphics package called Tkinter.  When you write:

```
L1 = Line(Point(x1,y1), Point(x2,y2))
L1.draw(win)
```

you create a (Zelle) graphics.py object asking it to draw itself.  There are other methods it can also respond to, as a subclass of `GraphicsObject`, including `move()`, `undraw()`, `setWidth()`, etc.

When you write:

```
L1 = win.create_line(x1, y1 , x2, y2)
```

you create a Tkinter object which responds to Tkinter methods.

As a rule, you should pick one level and work within it.  If you want to use (Zelle) graphics.py then you should avoid the Tkinter underpinnings until you run into something that the (Zelle) graphics.py simply can't do unless you drop down to the Tkinter level.  This will help ensure your objects play nice with each other.